# Proof using the fixed point theorem

Tags: limits, continuity, proof-writing, solution-verification, problem-solving

[image]

We have just started learning about continuity and this is basically the first assignment on this subject so I'm very unsure about how everything works. My attempt of a solution is as follows;

Let $g:\left[0,\frac{1}{2}\right]\ ->\left[0,\frac{1}{2}\right]\ $such that  $ g\left(x\right)\ =\ f\left(x\right)\ -\ f\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)$
Note that $g$ is continuous, hence by the fixed point theorem there exists a point $C$ in $\left[0,\frac{1}{2}\right]$ such that $g\left(C\right)\ =\ C$.

Therefore there exists a $C$ in $\left[0,\frac{1}{2}\right]$ such that $ g\left(C\right)\ =\ f\left(C\right)\ -\ f\left(C+\frac{1}{2}\right)$.

Now am I missing something? Because it seems just too simple to me..
also I didn't even use the fact the $f(0) = f(1)$ which is suspicious.

Edit: I'm seeing now that i didn't use the theorem correctly, since it just says that $g\left(C\right)\ =\ f\left(C\right)\ -\ f\left(C+\frac{1}{2}\right)= C $. and C is not necessarily $0$..

Comment: You need to use intermediate value theorem rather

Answer (score 0):

Your function $g$ may not *necessarily* be a self-map of $ [0,\frac{1}{2}]$ (and thus you can’t use the fixed point theorem justifiably). Rather it is only guaranteed (as you have noted) that it is continuous on $[0,\frac{1}{2}]$ and satisfies  $$g(0)=f(0)-f(\frac{1}{2})\,~\,~\,~ and \,~\,~\,~g(\frac{1}{2})=f(\frac{1}{2})-f(1)\,.$$ Since $f(0)=f(1)$, it follows that $$g(0)=-g(\frac{1}{2})\,.$$
Thus either $g(0)=0$ —— in which case $f(0)=f(\frac{1}{2})$ —— or by the Intermediate Value Theorem there exists $x_0\in (0,\frac{1}{2})$ such that $g(x_0)=0$ — that is $f(x_0)=f(x_0+\frac{1}{2})$.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on how I can use the IVT in this case?

Comment: That’s what I just did in my answer above. If $g(0)\ne 0$, then either $g(0)<0$ and $g(\frac{1}{2})>0$ or $g(0)>0$ and $g(\frac{1}{2})<0$; you then apply IVT to claim that $g(x_0)=0$ for some $x_0\in(0, \frac{1}{2} )$.